# DynamoDB query by contains one of the values from array for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to query with an array `[apple, orange]` on category (also an array. showing below) and get data contains values of either `apple` or `orange`?

```
row1 | "category": [apple, orange, banana, watermelon]
row2 | "category": [banana, watermelon]
row3 | "category": [orange, watermelon]
```

I expect to get `row1, row3` as a result that contains either `apple` or `orange`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use **CONTAINS** function to check for values in the list. However, if you want to check multiple values, you need to use **logical OR condition** for each value.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

**Example:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : 'tableName',
    FilterExpression: "contains (category, :category1) OR contains (category, :category2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {   
        ':category1' : "apple",
        ':category2' : "orange"
    }
};
```

**Note:-**

I assumed you are going to use Scan API. If you are using Query API, please include the `KeyConditionExpression`.

Answer (score 11):

The question asked about `Query`, but it seems that it is unclear whether on `Scan` is the technology being used.  I will answer for each of those parts.

1. `Scan` is very expensive and where possible `Query` should be used.  `Scan` easily supports using `contains` to do what you asked.

   ```
   await db.scan({
     TableName : 'tableName',
     FilterExpression: "contains (category, :category1) OR contains (category, :category2)",
     ExpressionAttributeValues : {   
       ':category1' : "apple",
       ':category2' : "orange"
     }
   }).promise();
   ```
2. Given that Scan is inefficient, it would be better to have a strategy where the rows it the table can be returned using the `Query`.  `Query` does **NOT** support the `Contains` syntax and additionally must run only a single `HASH` value.  Two different rows with different `HASH` values cannot be returned in the same `Query`.  Assuming this criteria is met, then a custom index would need to be constructed.  There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on the number of categories that you have and if multiple categories can be assigned to reach row.  For 1 cat per row, a single indexed column works.  Otherwise, we'll need to construct a indexed column that is able to use the one of the other operators.
   That column would need to contain a composite value for all the categories of the row, such that `f(column_value, category_value_check) = true` for all possible categories.  In order to construct such a composite value, Amazon recommends using a [Z-Index](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/).